# How to properly extract payload from nestjs/jwt token?

Tags: javascript, object, nestjs, decode, access-token

I ran into a problem with decrypting a token in a project, I want to extract data from the incoming token, compare it with the data from the database, and then perform certain actions.
The problem is that when I get the payload from "jwtService.decode()", I can't access the "decodedJwt.email" field, nest complains that "decodedJwt" is not an object. But if you return typeof "decodedJwt" then the answer is a string. However, I cannot access the "email" field in the code itself. If I return "decodedJwt" in this function, then in postman I will get the very necessary object with the necessary fields, including the same "email" field. What's my mistake?

Reply from nest:
Property 'email' does not exist on type 'string | { [key: string]: any; }'.
Property "email" does not exist on type "string".ts(2339)

```
async refreshTokenByOldToken(authHeader: string) {
  const decodedJwt = this.jwtService.decode(authHeader.split(' ')[1])
  return decodedJwt.email
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the type. Tell explicitly what type it is.

```
type PayloadType = {
  email: string;
}

async refreshTokenByOldToken(authHeader: string) {
  const decodedJwt = this.jwtService.decode(authHeader.split(' ')[1]) as PayloadType;
  return decodedJwt.email
}
```

You can reference `PayloadType` other places as well for example in your service instead of `string | { [key: string]: any; }` you can have `string | PayloadType`.

[examples of type casting](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/type-casting/#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20doesn%27t%20have%20a,operator%20for%20type%20castings.)

Answer (score 0):

because your decodedJwt string is different data type. You access email information two cases;

1. If you [@nestjs/jwt](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt) package

```
const decoded: JwtPayload = this.jwtService.decode(yourAccessToken);

const email = decoded.email;
```

OR

2. Base 64 Converting

   ```
   const base64Payload = authHeader.split(" ")[1];    
   const payloadBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Payload, "base64");
   const updatedJwtPayload: JwtPayload = JSON.parse(payloadBuffer.toString()) as JwtPayload;

   const email = updatedJwtPayload.email;
   ```